# Mockery and method chaining in a dependency

Tags: php, laravel, tdd, mockery

i'm pretty new to test and especially to Mockery.

In a Laravel project, I have a class that wraps an external api library. Something like this:

```php
class ApiWrapper {

  private $api;

  public function __construct(ExternalApiLibrary $api)
  {
    $this->api = $api;
  }

  public function method()
  {
    $this->api->method1('Foo')
              ->method2('Bar')
              ->method3('Not');
  }

}
```

In my test class, I mock `ExternalApiLibrary` using mockery and I would like to test that the 3 methods are called with their parameters.

```php
public function test_that_works()
{
  $this->mock(ExternalApiLibrary::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
    $mock
      ->shouldReceive('method1')
      ->with('Foo');

    $mock
      ->shouldReceive('method2')
      ->with('Bar');

    $mock
      ->shouldReceive('method3')
      ->with('Not');
  });

  $apiWrapper = $this->app->make(ApiWrapper::class);
  $apiWrapper->method();
}
```

But I get
`Method Mockery_0_ExternalApiLibrary::method2() does not exist on this mock object`.

I understand the reason, but how can I test that those methods get called on that external library?

Comment: http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/demeter_chains.html

Comment: How can i test parameters of each "step" ?

"Arguments to all members of the chain (except the final call) are ignored in this process."

no way?

Comment: I'm not certain, but does adding ->andReturnSelf() to each of the mock calls help? Tbh, i'm not sure what object it returns if not defining it